# I keep getting "Stack around the variable 'judge' was corrupted."

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder

I can't seem to be able to get this to work properly, I keep getting "Stack around the variable 'judge' was corrupted". Where did I go wrong? It seems to run properly, but at the end I get the error after I close and my lowNum value won't seem to process correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 5;

double getJudgeData(int judge);
double findLowest(double num[SIZE]);
double findHighest(double num[SIZE]);

int main()
{
    double 
        judge[SIZE],
        highNum,
        lowNum;


    for(int num = 1; num <= SIZE; num++)
    {
        judge[num] = getJudgeData(num);
        highNum = findHighest(judge);
        lowNum = findLowest(judge);
    }

    cout << highNum << endl;
    cout << lowNum << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

double getJudgeData(int judge)
{
    double score;

    cout << "What is the score given by judge " << judge << "?" << endl;
    cin >> score;

    while(score < 0 || score > 10) 
    {
        cout << "Please enter a score between 0 and 10.\n\n";

        cout << "What is the score given by judge " << judge << "?" << endl;
        cin >> score;
    }

    return score;

}
double findHighest(double num[SIZE])
{
    double high = 0;

    for(int count=0;count<SIZE;count++)
    {
        if(num[count]>high)
        high=num[count];
    }

    return high;
}

double findLowest(double num[SIZE])
{
    double low = 10;

    for(int count=0;count<SIZE;count++)
    {
        if(num[count]<low)
        low=num[count];
    }

    return low;
}
```

Comment: `array[n]` has indices from 0 to n-1... your `judge[num] =` is broken given your array condition `num <= SIZE`

Comment: It has to be said, the compiler gave you very high quality information about where the problem lies, and all C++ programmers should be very vigilant about the bounds of arrays *always*

Answer (score 1):

C++ used arrays from 0 to n-1. Your code is using 1 to n, so you "run off the end" of the array judge (and corrupt the variable around it).

Suggest you close the question since it's just a typo.

Comment: I'm new here, how do I do that?